# Log the time when login password is incorrect in windows7

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have the following problem: i need to log in a log file somewhere the time at which an incorrect password is tried in an attempt to login in windows 7.
I seached the internet but was not able to find that.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All system login/authentication attempts are logged in the Security Audit Log within the Windows Event Viewer by default. These logs are written by the Local Security Authority Subsystem Service (LSASS.exe). It is possible to analyze these events and filter out the exact information that you want.